# Is there a way to find out all rows that have column value not having 23:59:59 as its hour:minute:seconds in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a timestamp column in a table. Is there a way to find all rows in that table that does not have time exactly `23:59:59` ?

For example

It would filtered out

```
2018-02-28 23:59:59
```

but not

```
2018-02-28 23:59:58
2018-02-29 12:59:59
```

Comment: Sure its possible, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pick the `TIME()` from the column and check if it's not '23:59:59'

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(column) != '23:59:59'
```